# App runned in docker and access to database run in docker

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i'm just starting with docker and i have an problem.

I'm woring in windows with wsl 2.0.

I've run postgres on port 5432 in docker, and it run well.
I've cretared java app, which has access do postgress on localhost:5432.
When i run app on Intellij, it works fine.

When i build and run this app in docker, i have error, that it can't connect to postgress.

I assume, that maybe i should change "localhost" to maybe IP, but i'm not yet sure how it works.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `docker compose`, your Java service can access your Postgres service using the Postgres service's name. Instead of `localhost`, it's probably `postgres:5432`. You set the Postgres service's name within your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
services:
  # (service name)
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
```

If that doesn't work, you can try Docker's default bridge network IP address: `172.17.0.1`. See [this article](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) for more information.

---

Docker Desktop for Windows has [special considerations](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/#system-requirements) for WSL 2 users. Make sure your system is properly configured.

Sometimes, Docker Desktop will bind to a different subnet for container networking than the default IP range. You can find out which subnet Docker Desktop is using by visiting the settings menu. Here's what it looks like on MacOS:

[image: Docker Desktop Network Settings for MacOS]

---

Let me know if any of these hostnames/IP addresses work.